# Error while setting up Tezster

Tags: node, testing

While running the command:

> sudo tezster setup

Encountered the error,

```
sudo tezster setup
[sudo] password for aditya: 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tezster/tezster.js:108
.action(async function(){
        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

How can these be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306997/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list-when-using-async

> Your version of NodeJS (6.11 LTS) is too old and does not support the
>   async/await features. The syntax error is a result of the Javascript
>   interpreter not recognizing the async token and getting confused about
>   arguments.
>
> Upgrade to NodeJS 7.6 or later.
>   https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await